# simple use of function in shell script

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I am trying to use the simple fuinction below. But i get error sayin unary oprator expected and the output is always `one`. Can any1 help me correct it.

```
#!/bin/bash
checkit ()
{
if [ $1 = "none" ]
then
     echo "none"
else
     echo "one"
fi
}
checkit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` is an argument to the entire script and not to the function `checkit()`. So send the same argument to the function too.

```
#!/bin/bash
checkit ()
{
if [ $1 = "none" ]
then
     echo "none"
else
     echo "one"
fi
}

checkit $1
```

This has to work.

Comment: that is the difference between using = and == ?

Comment: Always quote your variables: `[ "$1" = "none" ]` ... `checkit "$1"`

Comment: AFAICT there's no difference between "=" and "==" in Bash.

Comment: `[ $var == "" ]` ... if the variable `$var` is empty the test becomes, 
`[ == "" ]` and ends up throwing an error. It's always better to quote your variables as @glenn said.

Comment: $1 IS the argument to the function checkit (within the body of the function). $1 is the argument to the script OUTSIDE the body of the function - you just happen to be passing the argument to the script as the first parameter to the function

Comment: @randeepsp: answering your question about `=` and `==`: POSIX standard defines only `=` operator (see http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html), `==` is an extension supported by some shells and some implementations of `test`. You should always try to make your scripts portable and hence avoid `==`.

Comment: @Roman: But the shebang says "bash", not "sh", so it's perfectly fine to use Bash features.

Comment: I did not understand the negative vote casted for this answer. `:|`

Answer (score 0):

Surround `$1` with quotes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
checkit ()
{
if [ "$1" = "none" ]
then
     echo "none"
else
     echo "one"
fi
}
checkit
```

Comment: ths output is still one. also what is the difference between using = and ==

Comment: According to `man [` there is no such thing as using `==` in the expression. `=` compares strings.

Comment: if i just use the below , it works.
if [ "$1" = "none" ] 
then 
     echo "none" 
else 
     echo "one" 
fi

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[[` keyword instead of the `[` builtin:

```
#!/bin/bash
checkit ()
{
if [[ $1 = none ]]
then
     echo none
else
     echo one
fi
}
checkit
```

Please read the [Bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Comment: ths output is still one. also what is the difference between using = and ==

Comment: Of course the output is `one` because `$1` is empty, not `none`. Please read up some basics about programming in bash.

Comment: Actually I would argue to use `[` instead of `[[` because `[[` is non-standard and is not supported by some shells. Just remember to quote your variables properly.